Gnucash price retrieval failed
I am using Windows 11, Gnucash 5.8 and price retieval is installed.
When I try to get quotes at the Price Database I get:
"Price retrieval failed: Failed to parse result returned by Finance::Quote
Error message:
(1)expected value
Result "
followed by all the share names etc
Please help me out
Thanks

Have you tried the trouble-shooting ay https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2020-July/092225.html to check ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY  and to bring back a quote through PowerShell, and at https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2016-October/067038.html, such as disabling quick retrieval on all but one security?
